# A python function with a complicated argument

Tags: python, function

I have a function in a python code whose argument is as follows:

```
save_geometry(r"""C:\Users\User0\Documents\test.txt """)
```

I want to modify the argument and be able to save to a different path with a different filename:

```
filename = "geometries.txt "
filepath = "D:/AllData/"
filefullpath = filepath + filename
```

Could someone help me how I should pass `filefullpath` to `save_geometry`? If there were no `r` in the argument of `save_geometry`, it would be easy. But I don't know how to deal with this `r`.

Comment: `save_geometry(filefullpath)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The r"" construct just tells Python that whatever's in the string should be interpreted as raw data.

```
"qw\n" == 'qw\n'
r"qw\n" == 'qw\\n'.
```

It's used because the "\" path separator is also used for newlines and such. You can skip it when putting in the argument; save_geometry(filefullpath) should do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the canonical way of putting together paths is [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

```
path = os.path.join("D:\\", "AllData", "geometries.txt")
```

User3757614's answer addresses your concern of the raw string notation, but succinctly all the `r""` notation does is tell Python that the following string should not treat `\` as an escape character, but as a literal backslash. This is important since `"C:\new folder"` is actually

```
C:
ew folder
```

Since `\n` is a newline.

Answer (score -2):

You cans use the `os` module to split your string into a folder path and file name.

e.g.

```
import os
pathname = os.path.dirname('C:\Users\User0\Documents\test.txt')  #C:\Users\User0\Documents
filename = os.path.basename('C:\Users\User0\Documents\test.txt')  #test.txt
```

Though you'll need to modify your path string because your `\`s will be interpreted and newline bytes